# Felicaリーダーで取得した入出場駅コードから駅名を取得する方法

Tags: c#

Suicaを読み取るライブラリを使ってC#で経路や費用を管理するツールを作成するため、Suica内部で保持する路線や駅のコードから名称を取得する仕組みを探しています。

FelicaリーダーでSuicaを読み込み、SFCard Viewerで表示すると路線名や駅名が取得できます。
[image: SFCard Viewerのスクリーンショット]

[felicalib](http://felicalib.tmurakam.org/index.html)で路線や駅をコードで取得できますが、名称はSuica内部で保持しておりません。

```
端末種:自販機 処理:物販 18/07/18  17:02 入:f3/60 残高:15009 連番:337
端末種:改札機 処理:運賃支払 18/07/18 入:1/3 出:2/3 残高:15159 連番:336
端末種:改札機 処理:運賃支払 18/07/18 入:e3/38 出:e3/37 残高:15313 連番:334
端末種:改札機 処理:運賃支払 18/07/18 入:e3/37 出:e3/38 残高:15478 連番:332
```

※17:02の`f3/60`の物販は東京駅構内での自販機購入データです。

このコードと路線名や駅名が紐づけされたデータやサービスは鉄道会社各社のホームページなどで一般公開されているものでしょうか。

独自にデータを収集して公開してくださっているサイトもあるのですが、もし公式に公開している一次データがあればそちらを参照したい(けれど見つからない)と思い、質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

felicalibのwikiに記載がありました。

[suica - FeliCa Library Wiki - FeliCa Library](https://ja.osdn.net/projects/felicalib/wiki/suica)

(鉄道会社等の)公式ドキュメント等で情報が用意されているわけではないので、有志で情報を突き合わせてまとめている様子です。

[路線・駅コード一覧・登録](http://www.denno.net/SFCardFan/)

Comment: 一般公開している公式ドキュメントがどうしても見つからなかったので質問に至りましたが、有志でまとめる状況について承知しました。IC SFCard Fan様のSoapサービスなど、公式情報よりも便利な収集情報で対応致します。サイトによってライセンスが不明瞭な場合もあるので、注意しながら活用します。ありがとうございました。